# Go: How to use the func() bool arguments in go?

Tags: go, markdown

This is a sample code from the Go [blackfriday](https://github.com/russross/blackfriday) package:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/russross/blackfriday"
)

func main() {

input := []byte(`##Title

- another paragragh

This is a being rendered in a custom way.
`)

    htmlFlags := 0
    renderer := &renderer{Html: blackfriday.HtmlRenderer(htmlFlags, "", "").(*blackfriday.Html)}

    extensions := 0

    unsanitized := blackfriday.Markdown(input, renderer, extensions)
    os.Stdout.Write(unsanitized)
}

// renderer implements blackfriday.Renderer and reuses blackfriday.Html for the most part,
// except overriding Link rendering.
type renderer struct {
    *blackfriday.Html
}

func (options *renderer) Header(out *bytes.Buffer, text func() bool, level int, id string) {
    fmt.Fprintf(out, "<custom link %q to %q>", content, link)
}
```

The purpose of the code is to customize the `link` attributes of the output HTML.

I tried to do the same but with `p` tags:

```
func (options *renderer) Paragraph(out *bytes.Buffer, text func() bool) {
    fmt.Fprintf(out, "<p class='custom'>%q</p>", text)
}
```

But the output was this:

```
<h1>Title</h1>

<ul>
<li>another paragragh</li>
</ul>
<p class='custom'>%!q(func() bool=0x80a15d0)</p>
```

So I have no idea how to output the actual text (`This is a being rendered in a custom way.`). Any ideas?

This is the source code of the function:

```
func (options *Html) Paragraph(out *bytes.Buffer, text func() bool) {
    marker := out.Len()
    doubleSpace(out)

    out.WriteString("<p>")
    if !text() {
        out.Truncate(marker)
        return
    }
    out.WriteString("</p>\n")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your usage of function is wrong.

Take a look at [`Html.Paragraph`](https://github.com/russross/blackfriday/blob/f4bb968b5f379b73adac606686bbfe96e57339ec/html.go#L401) and override this.

Maybe it would look like:

```
func (options *renderer) Paragraph(out *bytes.Buffer, text func() bool) {
    marker := out.Len()
    doubleSpace(out) 

    out.WriteString("<p class='custom'>")
    if !text() {
        out.Truncate(marker)
        return
    }
    out.WriteString("</p>\n")
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work because when you use `doubleSpace(out)` out of the package you get an undefined variable error.

Comment: Yes, it's private function so you somehow rewrite it or write alternative one.

Answer (score 1):

I believe all you need to do is call `text`

```
func (options *renderer) Paragraph(out *bytes.Buffer, text func() bool) {
    fmt.Fprintf(out, "<p class='custom'>%q</p>\n", text())
}
```

Comment: Thanks but now it outputs: `This is a <a href="http://www.example.org/">link</a> being rendered in a custom way.<p class='custom'>%!q(bool=true)</p>`

Comment: Ah, right, text returns a `bool`.  I would need to look further to see how paragraph content is injected because it does not appear the default Paragraph function does it.  Give @Jaemin's answer a try.